# Comparing two data with chi-square test in python

Tags: python, p-value, chi-squared

I have two spectra which have (wavelength, flux, error) columns.  Two spectra are similar to each other except that one has a small shift in wavelength as compared to the other. I have measured the shift by cross-correlating the two spectra. Now, my goal is to measure the chi-square between the two spectra before and after applying the measured shift to one of the spectra.  For Chi-sq estimation,  I am taking my second spectra as the model. Computing the chi-square is easy.  But, how can I estimate the p-values associated with these chi-squares in python?

Comment: Please share the code you are having problems with. Is the p-values produced by that code faulty? Or are you asking us to write the code for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [scipy.stats.chisquare](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chisquare.html)

```
>>> from scipy.stats import chisquare
>>> chisquare([16, 18, 16, 14, 12, 12],f_exp=[16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 8])
Power_divergenceResult(statistic=3.5, pvalue=0.62338762774958223)
```

The first input is the observed frequencies and the second input is the expected frequencies.

The second output is the p-value.